# sql query optimization with concat and inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am running this query, it takes a very long time to run over 400 seconds. I only have 20K records in the ticket table. I want to minimize to a few seconds

```
select A.ticket_id, A.ticket_number,
       P.ticket_id, P.ticket_number,
       count(P.ticket_number) as cnt
   from       ticket A
   inner join ticket P  on A.ticket_id != P.ticket_id
where
((A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick1,2,0), "%"))
(A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick2,2,0), "%"))
(A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick3,2,0), "%"))
(A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick4,2,0), "%"))
(A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick5,2,0), "%"))
(A.ticket_number like concat("%", lpad(P.pick6,2,0), "%")) > 3)
group by A.ticket_id
having cnt > 11;
```

Is there any way I can minimize the execution of this query?

Comment: which db you are really using  ????

Comment: Does ticket_number or pick1..6 have some sort of fixed format? Cam you give examples of the content?

Comment: This join: `ticket A inner join ticket P on A.ticket_id != P.ticket_id` will give you approximately 20000*20000 rows to scan...

Comment: what actually you are trying to achieve using this query? Can you elaborate bit more.

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect.  You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want the query to do.

Comment: You have strange syntax:  `WHERE ( (expr1) (expr2) ...)`  Shouldn't there be an `AND` or `OR` or `+` between the expressions?